# Lambda IfThenElse expression with another lambda inside (for SetQueryFilter())

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

My goal is to have filter for `IMutableEntityType`, where I select data rows by `CurrentTenantId` column value.
For more context, please see: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23718

This is already done by me:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
                
// TODO: This filter is working, but we must prevent filtering with TenantId = 0
var workingFilter = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(parameter, colName),
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23718
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(myContext), currentTenantIdMemberInfo)
        ),
    parameter);

entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);
```

But I want to get all entities if `TenantId == 0`, so I wrote this Lambda:

```
var conditionalExpression = Expression.IfThenElse(
    // Check if TenantId > 0
    Expression.GreaterThan(
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(myContext), currentTenantIdMemberInfo),
        Expression.Constant((long) 0)
        ),
    // build filter: (p) => p.{colName} == {myContext.CurrentTenantId}
    // i.e. (p) => p.TenantId == 123)
    Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, colName),

            // See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23718
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(myContext), currentTenantIdMemberInfo)
            )//,
        ),
    // TenantId <= 0, so act like (p => p)
    Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(parameter)) // just p // TODO: Not working
    //Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(parameter), parameter) // p => p // TODO: Also not working...
);

var filter = Expression.Lambda(conditionalExpression);
```

But after calling `entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);` I have `InvalidOperationException`:

```
'The filter expression '() => IIF((value(My.Project.MyContext).CurrentTenantId > 0), () => (p.TenantId == value(My.Project.MyContext).CurrentTenantId), () => p)' specified for entity type 'MyEntity' is invalid. The expression must accept a single parameter of type 'My.Project.MyEntity' and return bool.'
```

And my question is - how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. You have missed adding `parameter` to Lambda and made mistakes with lambda usage. Also selected shortest way to do that.

```cs
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");

// EF just needs to know that you have member access to DbContext
var contextExpr = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(MyContext));
var tenantExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(contextExpr, currentTenantIdMemberInfo);

var conditionalExpression = Expression.OrElse(
    // Check if TenantId <= 0
    Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
        tenantExpr,
        Expression.Constant((long) 0)
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, colName),
            tenantExpr
        )
    )
);

var filter = Expression.Lambda(conditionalExpression, parameter);

entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);
```

Also you are not alone and this task has been done by a lot of libraries, for example [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/552c0240c44d9899c1209fb20eb48d35b17d5e54/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L129)

For simplifying such tasks, I strongly recommend to use Expression Tree visualisers:
https://github.com/agileobjects/ReadableExpressions
https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer

Comment: Thank you. I already implemented it in this same way 3 days ago - Smit from EF Core Team answered it faster (see URL in my question). I marked your answer as accepted. Merry Christmas and happy New Year.